# progress dialog en asyntask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Tengo una clase que utiliza una asyntask para guardar datos en una base de datos, funciona todo bien, hasta el momento donde quiero agregar un progressdialog para la espera de la inserción en la base de datos, les dejo mi codigo actual, espero puedan ayudarme

```
public class RegisterShopPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre, contraseña, email, cumple, comuna;
    String un, pass, db, ip;
    TextView boton;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    Connection con;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_shop);

        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombreR);
        contraseña = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passR);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mailR);
        cumple = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cumpleR);
        comuna = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.viveR);
        boton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_register_shop_submit);
        ip = getResources().getString(R.string.host);
        db = getResources().getString(R.string.db);
        un = getResources().getString(R.string.user);
        pass = getResources().getString(R.string.pass);


        boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RegisterShopPageActivity.CheckLogin checkLogin = new RegisterShopPageActivity.CheckLogin();
                checkLogin.execute("");
            }
        });

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        String z = "";
        String mail = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = contraseña.getText().toString().trim();
        String nombreUser = nombre.getText().toString().trim();
        String nacimiento=cumple.getText().toString().trim();
        String vive=comuna.getText().toString().trim();
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterShopPageActivity.this, "Creando Usuario","Por favor espera", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if(z.equals("Debes completar los 3 campos solicitados")){
                TastyToast.makeText(RegisterShopPageActivity.this,z, TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR).show();
            }else if (z.equals("Inserta un nombe valido")){
                TastyToast.makeText(RegisterShopPageActivity.this, z, TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR).show();
            }else if(r.trim().contains("The email address is already in use by another account.".trim())){
                TastyToast.makeText(RegisterShopPageActivity.this,"El email ya esta en uso", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.INFO).show();
            }else if (r.trim().contains("The email address is badly formatted".trim())){
                TastyToast.makeText(RegisterShopPageActivity.this,"Formato de correo invalido" , TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.INFO).show();
            }else if(r.trim().contains("An internal error has occurred. [ WEAK_PASSWORD  ]".trim())){
                TastyToast.makeText(RegisterShopPageActivity.this,"La contraseña es muuy debil", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.INFO).show();
            }else if(r.trim().contains("A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.".trim())){
                TastyToast.makeText(RegisterShopPageActivity.this,"Conexión a internet perdida", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR).show();
            } else if(z.equals("funciono")){
                email.setText("");
                contraseña.setText("");
                nombre.setText("");
                cumple.setText("");
                comuna.setText("");
                TastyToast.makeText(RegisterShopPageActivity.this,"Usuario creado con exito, por favor verifique su direccion de correo electronico", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.SUCCESS).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (mail.equals("") && password.equals("") && nombreUser.equals("") && nacimiento.equals("") && vive.equals("")) {
                z = "Debes completar los campos solicitados";
            }
            if (nombreUser.length() < 1) {
                z = "El nombre debe tener al menos 10 caracteres";
            }else if(mail.equals("") || password.equals("") || nombreUser.equals("") || nacimiento.equals("") || vive.equals("")){
                z = "Debes completar los 3 campos solicitados";
            }else {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterShopPageActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d("funciona", "pase por aqui");
                                    try {
                                        con = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);
                                        if (con == null) {
                                        } else {
                                            try {
                                                String pass = AESCrypt.encrypt("encryp", password);
                                                String query = "insert Into usuarios values('"+nombreUser+"','"+mail+"','"+pass+"',((SELECT CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()))),'"+vive+"','"+nacimiento+"');";
                                                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                                                preparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(2);
                                                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                                                con.close();
                                                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                                                        "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.perfilvacio)
                                                        + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.perfilvacio) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.perfilvacio));

                                                final FirebaseUser update = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                                                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                                        .setDisplayName(nombreUser)
                                                        .setPhotoUri(imageUri)
                                                        .build();

                                                update.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                            update.sendEmailVerification();
                                                            TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Verifica tu dirección de email",TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.INFO).show();
                                                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                                        } else {
                                                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                                                Log.d("error de encriptacion", e.getMessage());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        Log.d("error base de datos: ", ex.getMessage());
                                    }
                                }else if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Exception e=task.getException();
                                    try {
                                        throw e;
                                    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                                        onPostExecute(e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                    Log.d("no funciono",e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                z = "funciono";
            }
            return z;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server +"/"+ database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";";
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(2);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

este es el logcat con el error que tengo

```
05-28 21:29:10.080 25416-25416/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.RegisterShopPageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{19cb5c08 V.E..... R......D 0,0-575,250} that was originally added here
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:367)
                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:306)
                                                                                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
                                                                                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
                                                                                      at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.RegisterShopPageActivity$CheckLogin$override.onPreExecute(RegisterShopPageActivity.java:101)
                                                                                      at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.RegisterShopPageActivity$CheckLogin$override.access$dispatch(RegisterShopPageActivity.java)
                                                                                      at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.RegisterShopPageActivity$CheckLogin.onPreExecute(RegisterShopPageActivity.java:0)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                                                                                      at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.RegisterShopPageActivity$1.onClick(RegisterShopPageActivity.java:67)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

a mi parecer creo que es por que algún método en el doInBackgrounds, tiene algo que modifica la actividad y hace que se pierda el context de la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo que explica este [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83)

Debes pasar al `asyntask` la referencia de la actividad con `WeakReference`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
    }
    private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

        private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivity;    

        public MyAsyncTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {   
            this.mainActivity = new WeakReference<>(mainActivity);            
        }
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            return doSomeStuff();
        }
        private Object doSomeStuff() {
            //do something to get result
            return new Object();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object object) {
            super.onPostExecute(object);
            if (mainActivity.get() != null){
                //accede a los componentes de mainactivity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otra solución es usar observables [aquí el tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/weakreference-in-android-dd1e66b9be9d)

También puede ser que cuando la actividad se cierre y la tarea background continua y al finalizar, no encuentra la referencia del dialogo:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if ( progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing() ){
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: revise ambos tutoriales y me sirvieron en parte, pero no del todo, ejecuta el dialogo durante un segundo, y se cierra, ya no se detiene la aplicación, necesito que el dialogo termine en el método onPostExecute(), para tener  la solución al 100%

Comment: Pronto tendré que implementar algo parecido y si lo consigo lo publicare.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera.
Declaro el ProgressDialog como atributo de la clase principal, en este caso dentro de RegisterShopPageActivity.
Lo inicializo y muestro en el método onPreExecute del Asynktask y lo cierro en el postExecute, similar a lo que haces tu pero no igual.

```
public class RegisterShopPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ...

    public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterShopPageActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Espere...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);  //Las propiedades que quieras
            dialog.setCancelable(false);    //Las propiedades que quieras
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {...}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ...
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Si lo haces así, el ProgressDialog se cierra una vez que ha acabado el código que escribas en el método onPostExecute